# Joomla loadmodule or loadposition inside CiviCRM

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla

please how can I use {loadmodule xxx} or {loadposition xxx} inside:
- an event description
- a profile intro field

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do that, at least not without programming. Event descriptions and profile intro fields are rendered by CiviCRM, not Joomla, and CiviCRM does not process Joomla plugins.

If you have the event page linked to a Joomla menu item then of course you can display a module elsewhere on the page (outside of the CiviCRM-generated content).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Modules Anywhere](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere) extension - see an example in action on [this event registration page](https://www.evergreenmtb.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register&id=272&reset=1) (the yellow box prompting users to log in is a module). 
I'm not the developer - just a happy user.